# XMPP:BOSH client session getting closed randomly while connecting to openfire

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, instant-messaging

I get this message after sometime.

```
 org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession - Request 3436024236568502 > 3436024236568501, ending session.
```

Basically I send around 1,00,000 messages/queue/hour each of 400 bytes. I see that only this session is terminated .

What does this message indicate and what s the possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run into the following constraint

```
else if (rid > (lastRequestID + maxRequests)) {
    Log.warn("Request " + rid + " > " + (lastRequestID + maxRequests) + ", ending session.");
        throw new HttpBindException("Unexpected RID error.",
                BoshBindingError.itemNotFound);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/c99af1e734df7f5befdf57c478ea0733d5ac236c/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/http/HttpSession.java#L752)

Which means there are to many outstanding BOSH requests. [Openfire defaults to 2](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/c6dd1ae4d331924e04635dbae1887872954ea3ad/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/http/HttpSessionManager.java#L271). You could try to modify the Openfire settings `xmpp.httpbind.client.requests.max`, but I would not recommend doing so. Instead ensure that your BOSH client only sends new requests if there is no more then 1 outstanding one.