# What if 5222 port/domain is blocked for Xmpp

Tags: security, google-chrome, xmpp, openfire, smack

I have a java Client(Smack API) connecting Openfire server which listens at port 5222.

In one of the deployement scenarios the firewall has blocked 5222(tcp xmpp client communication). Tried using BOSH(Blabber library) , but its not able to handle the load. Whats the solution for this scenario?

I read that even Gtalk uses 5222 but if the network firewall blocks it, they are able to connect seamlessly thru 443 or port 80. How does it work? whats the protocol being used.

Answer (score 1):

If 5222 is blocked, xmpp client over insecure connexions can't connect to your server.
But BOSH is listening over the port 7070 with connect (7070 for unsecure connexion)
In other case, you can post the logs

Comment: please check this  ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121988/xmppbosh-client-session-getting-closed-randomly-while-connecting-to-openfire/30123242#30123242